# Spring Roo dependencies, status: 405 Not Allowed

Tags: maven, spring-roo

Hello i have this problem, when i launch : mvn clean install

> Downloading from spring-roo-repository-release:
> http://repo.spring.io/spring-roo/org/springframework/roo/wrapping/org.springframewo
> rk.roo.wrapping.inflector/0.7.0.010/org.springframework.roo.wrapping.inflector-0.7.0.010.pom
> [WARNING] The POM for
> org.springframework.roo:org.springframework.roo.querydsl.processor:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE
> is missing, no dependenc y information available [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time:  3.457 s [INFO] Finished at:
> 2023-10-18T16:47:38+01:00 [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project demo: Could not resolve
> dependencies for project com.rc.demo:demo:jar:1.4: Faile d to
> collect dependencies at
> org.springframework.roo:org.springframework.roo.annotations:pom:2.0.0.RELEASE
> -> org.springframework.r oo:org.springframework.roo.classpath:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE ->
> org.springframework.roo.wrapping:org.springframework.roo.wrapping.inflect
> or:jar:0.7.0.010: Failed to read artifact descriptor for
> org.springframework.roo.wrapping:org.springframework.roo.wrapping.inflecto
> r:jar:0.7.0.010: Could not transfer artifact
> org.springframework.roo.wrapping:org.springframework.roo.wrapping.inflector:pom:0.7.0.
> 010 from/to spring-roo-repository-release
> (http://repo.spring.io/spring-roo/): transfer failed for
> http://repo.spring.io/spring-roo
> /org/springframework/roo/wrapping/org.springframework.roo.wrapping.inflector/0.7.0.010/org.springframework.roo.wrapping.inflector-0
> .7.0.010.pom, status: 405 Not Allowed -> [Help 1] [ERROR] [ERROR] To
> see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e
> switch. [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug
> logging. [ERROR] [ERROR] For more information about the errors and
> possible solutions, please read the following articles: [ERROR] [Help
> 1]
> http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException

In my pom, i use :

> ```
> <repository>
>   <id>spring-roo-repository</id>
>   <name>Spring Roo Repository</name>
>   <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
>   <snapshots>
>       <enabled>true</enabled>
>   </snapshots>
>   <releases>
>       <enabled>true</enabled>
>   </releases>
> </repository>
> ```

any ideas ?

thanks

Comment: Why even using spring roo? The last release is of 2017? https://central.sonatype.com/namespace/org.springframework.roo

Comment: @khmarbaise , This is an old project that I have to work on.

Comment: Bad thing, because the spring repos are not available for access anymore (https://spring.io/blog/2022/12/14/notice-of-permissions-changes-to-repo-spring-io-january-2023) you have to use central only